# cannot subscript a value of type NSDictionary with an index of type string

Tags: swift, indexing, subscript

```
    var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!

    var request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.setValue("Basic \(base64EncodedCredential)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

    var dataVal: NSData =  NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil, error:nil)!

    var err: NSError
    println(dataVal)


    //var jsonResult : NSDictionary?
    var jsonResult  = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataVal, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as? NSDictionary

    println("Synchronous  \(jsonResult)")
    jsonResult["records"]
```

Here is where the error happens, I just want to take one value from my `jsonResult`, which is printed correctly at the console.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are typecasting the jsonResult as `NSDictionary`, instead use `[String:AnyObject]`

If you are using `NSDictionary`, you should use `valueForKey(key)` or `objectForKey(key)` methods of `NSDictionary` to get value for the key.

```
    var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
    var err: NSError?

        var request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        request.setValue("Basic \(base64EncodedCredential)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

        var dataVal: NSData =  NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil, error:nil)!

        var err: NSError
        println(dataVal)


        //var jsonResult : NSDictionary?
        var jsonResult:AnyObject?  = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataVal, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves, error: &err)  

        println("Synchronous  \(jsonResult)")
        if let result = jsonResult as? [String: AnyObject] {
           if let oneValue = result["records"] as? String { //Here i am considering value for jsonResult["records"] as String, if it other than String, please change it.
             println(oneValue)
           }
       }
```

Comment: var jsonResult  = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataVal, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves, error: &err) use this line.

Comment: Are you sure the result will be dictionary, instead of Array. Now check the edited answer.

Comment: yes friend i solved like this if let user = parsedObject as? NSDictionary {
            if let xxxx = user["xxxx"] as? NSDictionary {
                if let xxxx = records["xxxx"] as? NSString {
                    //3
                        println("Optional Binding: \(xxxx)")

                }
            }
        }

Comment: If it helped, accept as correct answer. It will help others too. :)

Comment: Hi! please what if I want to assign `oneValue` to a label? when I make it as label.text = oneValue in the console I got Optional(xxx) and the label is not set because the optional is like nil. Any help please?